# AJAX Post request in laravel 5.4

Tags: ajax, post, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Have anyone got issue in ajax post request in laravel 5.4. I am unable to get request data in controller.
Ajax request is something like this:

```
$.ajax({
     data: { 'selected_data':[2,4,5] },
     type: "POST",
     url: "{{ url('test') }}",
     headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
     success: function (res) {
         console.log(res)
     },
});
```

In controller method, i am just doing

```
dd($request->all());
```

But getting empty array. can anyone help me with this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your full controller method?

Comment: Verify if you are using post route for your controller method or not.

Comment: Thanks @JoshBolton & Mann verma for your suggestion. Issue solved.It was due to another bug.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
$.ajax({
 data: { 'selected_data':[2,4,5] },
 type: "POST",
 url: "{{ url('test') }}",
 headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
 success: function (res) {
     console.log(res)
 },
});
```

Try this:

```
 $.ajax({
 data: { selected_data:[2,4,5], _token: "{{csrf_token()}}" },
 type: "POST",
 url: "{{ url('test') }}",
 success: function (res) {
     console.log(res)
 },
});
```